# CTR in our Google Admob account has increased a lot, invalid activity

Tags: admob

CTR in our Google Admob account has increased a lot, we feel that there is an invalid activity in our account. How can we stop this invalid activity ??? And how much AdMob's CTR is safe?

Comment: higher CTR is good for revenue generation, why you feel there is invalid activity. Make sure you follow admob implementation guidelines given by google for developers to control invalid implementation of admob. Invalid activity is monitor by google and they take appropriate action

Comment: 1. Can I have more than a CTR account suspense ?? 

2. If someone is doing an inline activity in our app then does it have an effect in our account ??

Comment: 1.Account will not be suspended if its valid clicks.2.  Google monitors suspicious clicks and suspends account. If you sure those are not done by you. You can always file an appeal. You cannot control other's doing it on purpose. They will be caught. If you have enough proof you can always file appeal in case of suspension

Comment: follow this link - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342099?hl=en

Comment: We think our competitor  in our app are deliberately doing illegal activity in our app, so that our account is suspended. How can we stop them?